# mongodb library don`t work with json childrens

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, aws-lambda

I try filter search in my mongoDB. For it, i using `find({}).project({a:0, b:1})`, its workin!

But when trying `find({}).project({a.b.c:0, b.c.d:1})` i get the return:

```sh
{ MongoError: Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion.
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/joaquimflavio/Documents/GitHub/Simemap_repo/lambda_get_mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:466:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at processMessage (/Users/joaquimflavio/Documents/GitHub/Simemap_repo/lambda_get_mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:364:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/joaquimflavio/Documents/GitHub/Simemap_repo/lambda_get_mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:533:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion.',
  code: 2,
  codeName: 'BadValue',
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: Once in projection you need to include or exclude or use 0, 1 except _id

Comment: First one should throw the same error as well! [check here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qLwtDcYKdoE), and [the one with dots](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FcAUq4eQQOq) also failing with same error as it is in your question. You can just add all the fields you'd like to keep with `field: 1`, and just don't include the ones that you'd want to add with `field: 0` that will be the same result with what you are trying to do.

Comment: But i can`t make `filed: 0` with children json object?